# Firebase w/ React how to automate current time?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a web application with that i can add 'listings'. There is a time limit of each listing. 5, 10, and 15 minutes. React renders the listings well, but since there is a time limit, it calculates the difference between time now and time added(when the listing was added). This way it starts a countdown. However currently there is an extra nodejs backend that updates the current time value in the database, plus it also checks for expired listings and delete them.

The question is, how can i update the current time on firebase without using external nodejs backend? Cloud functions of firebase can only be triggered by an event, but i need to update the current time in every seconds so react can calculate the expire time. Any way to do this with firebase?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than triggering a firebase function on an event you can create a http trigger and then use a site like https://cron-job.org/en/. That's just the site I use, it's simple but there are other options. You can't trigger the function every second, I think 1 minute is the minimum.

Here is a write-up https://medium.com/google-cloud/startups-now-cronjob-your-google-firebase-functions-securely-and-externally-without-paying-for-503b0f4ca539

You can also set up an app engine, more reliable but slightly more involved. Details here https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html